# How to save a list by element in a Singleton object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I have a Singleton class where I have two methods, one to save elements in a singleton list and another one to get all save products. Notice that the products will be save one by one.

My problem is that I always save the last element and only have one in the singleton. How can I do it to save all the elements that I want to put in the singleton.

```
class VoucherRepository {

    object Singleton {
        var vouchers: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf<Product>()
    }


    fun addProductToShoppingCart(voucherProduct: Product){
        Singleton.vouchers.add(voucherProduct)
    }

    fun getProductsInShoppinCart() : List<Product>?{
        return Singleton.vouchers
    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
class ProductRepository {

    companion object Singleton {
        var vouchers: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf<Product>()

        fun addProductToShoppingCart(voucherProduct: Product){
            vouchers.add(voucherProduct)
        }

        fun getProductsInShoppinCart() : List<Product>?{
            return vouchers
        }

        fun cleanProductsInShoppinCart(){
            vouchers.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show example code? I was not able to reproduce issue.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
    val repo = VoucherRepository()

    println(VoucherRepository.Singleton.vouchers) // []
    repo.addProductToShoppingCart("aaa")
    println(VoucherRepository.Singleton.vouchers) // [aaa]
    repo.addProductToShoppingCart("bbb")
    println(VoucherRepository.Singleton.vouchers) // [aaa, bbb]

    VoucherRepository().addProductToShoppingCart("ccc")
    println(VoucherRepository.Singleton.vouchers) // [aaa, bbb, ccc]
    println(repo.getProductsInShoppinCart()) // [aaa, bbb, ccc]
    println(VoucherRepository().getProductsInShoppinCart()) // [aaa, bbb, ccc]

}

class VoucherRepository {

    object Singleton {
        var vouchers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    }


    fun addProductToShoppingCart(voucherProduct: String) {
        Singleton.vouchers.add(voucherProduct)
    }

    fun getProductsInShoppinCart() : List<String> {
        return Singleton.vouchers
    }
}
```

It looks like your singleton was released from memory somehow and initialized again and again, but without more code I cannot help.

Comment: Yes, seems that is initialized everytime I add an element. Look my new approach that is doing correctly

Comment: Oh, that's great! But how do you initialize `Repository`? Is it initialized multiple times? What framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**This technique is similar to builder pattern**

---

it will save all the Products to a temporary MutableList and after successful addition of all the products to tempVauchers it will initialize the singleton and you can get the singleton by calling getVauchers()*

**Singleton Class**

```
 class VoucherRepository {
      object Singleton {
          var vouchers: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf<Product>()
       }
    }
```

**Use blow code to add products**

```
 var tempVauchers: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf<Product>()

        fun compileCart(voucherProduct: String, isComplete: Boolean){
            if(!isComplete){
                tempVauchers.add(voucherProduct)
            }else{
                VoucherRepository.vouchers = tempVauchers
            }

        }
```

**get Singleton**

```
fun getVauchers(): MutableList<Product> {
    return VoucherRepository.vouchers
 }
```